# How to align equations inside \abs command of the physics package

Tags: equations, align, physics

I am using the `physics` package and running into a problem while aligning equations

```
\begin{align}
    \psi(\bm{z}) &= h`(\bm{w}^T\bm{z} + b)\bm{w}\\
    \abs\Big{det\pdv{f}{\bm{z}}} = \abs{det(\bm{I} &+ \bm{u}\psi(\bm{z})^T)} = \abs{1 + \bm{u}^T\psi(\bm{z})}
\end{align}
```

The above code throws an error: possibly because the `&` alignment character is inside the `\abs{}`.

I can fix it by doing this:

```
\begin{align}
\psi(\bm{z}) &= h`(\bm{w}^T\bm{z} + b)\bm{w}\\
\abs\Big{det\pdv{f}{\bm{z}}} = 
     |det(\bm{I} &+ \bm{u}\psi(\bm{z})^T)| = 
     \abs{1 + \bm{u}^T\psi(\bm{z})}
\end{align}
```

If I do this however, I notice that `\abs{}` and `|.|` are of different sizes. How can I align the equation the way I want to and continue using `\abs{}` preferably?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{extarticle}

\usepackage{amsmath,bm,amssymb,amsthm,physics}

\begin{document}

%This doesn't work :(
%\begin{align}
%    \psi(\bm{z}) &= h`(\bm{w}^T\bm{z} + b)\bm{w}\\
%    \abs\Big{det\pdv{f}{\bm{z}}} = \abs{det(\bm{I} &+ \bm{u}\psi(\bm{z})^T)} = \abs{1 + \bm{u}^T\psi(\bm{z})}
%\end{align}

\begin{align}
    \psi(\bm{z}) &= h`(\bm{w}^T\bm{z} + b)\bm{w}\\
    \abs\Big{det\pdv{f}{\bm{z}}} = |det(\bm{I} &+ \bm{u}\psi(\bm{z})^T)| = \abs{1 + \bm{u}^T\psi(\bm{z})}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:**

On further investigation, there is something else wrong with the first snippet:
Removing \abs and changing det to \det is also causing an error. I am not sure what the problem is.

```
\begin{align}
    \psi(\z) &= h`(\w^T\z + b)\w\\
    \abs\Big{\det\pdv{f}{\z}} = |\det(\bm{I} &+ \bm{u}\psi(\z)^T)| = \abs{1 + \bm{u}^T\psi(\z)}
\end{align}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve in terms of typography, but it looks to me like you're trying to typeset each equation centered independently. If that's the case, just change both instances of `{align}` to {gather}` and remove the `&` alignment points.

Comment: @Mico I am trying to align the '=' in equation 1, with the first '+' symbol in equation 2 so that it looks better.

Comment: @Mico Your suggestion does make it look okay, but I would still like to understand the cause of the errors.

Comment: In aligned `amsmath` environments, each part delimited by `&` and/or `\\ ` should be a complete equation snippet which can be typeset independently. Hence input like `\left( ... & \right)` causes problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `physics` package can do a lot of useful things. It's also known, though, for making lexical assumptions about the meaning of parentheses and brackets that may or may not be appropriate. The fact that changing `det` to `\det` causes extra problems would appear to be related to this issue.

I suggest that unless you're heavily invested in the capabilities of the `physics` package, you load the `mathtools` package and provide your own definitions of `\abs`, `\pdv` etc, as is shown in the following example. Note that this approach allows the `&` alignment point to occur inside `\abs{...}` as well as inside `\det(...)`.

That said, I think the result of using a `gather` environment instead of an `align` environment is typographically superior (as well as simpler to create!) for the case at hand.

[image]

It's worth noting explicitly that there is a slight difference in syntax for using the `\abs` macro: With the `physics` package, one writes `\abs\Big{...}`, whereas with the `mathtools` version, one writes `\abs[\Big]{...}`. Hopefully, this doesn't pose an insurmountable obstacle to making the switch.

```
\documentclass{extarticle}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\DeclarePairedDelimiter' macro
\usepackage{bm} % for '\bm' macro
%% provide your own definitions of \abs, \pdv, etc as needed:
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs\lvert\rvert
\newcommand\pdv[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}

\begin{document}
Use \verb+gather+ and no alignment points:
\begin{gather}
    \psi(\bm{z}) = h'(\bm{w}^T\bm{z} + b)\bm{w}\\
    \abs[\Big]{\det\pdv{f}{\bm{z}}} 
      = \abs{\det(\bm{I} + \bm{u}\psi(\bm{z})^T)} 
      = \abs{1 + \bm{u}^T\psi(\bm{z})}
\end{gather}

\medskip
Use \verb+align+ and 1 alignment point per row:
\begin{align}
    \psi(\bm{z}) &= h'(\bm{w}^T\bm{z} + b)\bm{w}\\
    \abs[\Big]{\det\pdv{f}{\bm{z}}} 
      = \abs{\det(\bm{I} &+ \bm{u}\psi(\bm{z})^T)}
      = \abs{1 + \bm{u}^T\psi(\bm{z})}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```